# Why is my ListView presentin nothing, SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I have no Idea why my List View is empty, this is my Code:

```
List(asArray, id: \.self) { i in
                
        Text(i)
          .foregroundColor(.black)
}
```

And my Array is okay, because if I put instead of an ListView an ForEach Block, everything got presented.

```
ForEach(asArray, id: \.self) { i in
                
        Text(i)
          .foregroundColor(.black)
}
```

This code works perfekt.

Look, this Code works fine

```
ForEach(asArray, id: \.self) { i in
      Text(i)
}
```

but if i put the hole code in an list View, nothing is working

```
List{
   ForEach(asArray, id: \.self) { i in
         Text(i)
   }
}
```

Whyy? I have no Idea...

btw: this dont works too

```
    List {
    ForEach(0 ..< asArray.count) { index in
        Text(asArray[index])
            .foregroundColor(.black)
}
}
```

Thanks for your help.
Boothosh

Comment: Include enough code for a [mre].

Comment: my problem is that i dont know what is wrong and thats why i dont know wich code i should add

Comment: I mean if you run this code, (and declare an own array), then everything is working fine... I have no idea what could be possible reasons

Comment: Are you by any chance using a device in Dark Mode? by setting your `.foregroundColor(.black)` you make your text the same color as your background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Custom Classes/Structs**:

To ensure that your view presents correctly, make sure the ListView is not inside a ScrollView. Next, make sure that your array conforms to `Identifiable`. Once it conforms to identifiable, you can call the following:

```
List(asArray) { i in
    Text(i)
        .foregroundColor(.black)
}
```

When your array conforms to Identifiable, make sure that your class or struct has a variable named `id` so that you don't have to specify the id parameter in your ListView.

**Built-in classes/structs**:

You will need to do the following since some classes/structs built into Swift do not conform to `Identifiable`:

```
List {
    ForEach(0 ..< asArray.count) { index in
        Text(asArray[index])
            .foregroundColor(.black)
    }
}
```

Comment: That means String isn`t conform to the protocol Identifiable?

Comment: Yes, `String` does not conform to `Identifiable`, so it will not work in a dynamic list. You will need to use a `ForEach` as I have added in the second part of my answer.

Comment: But if I run your code it dont work too... i`ve updated my question

Comment: That is because you have not used my code correctly. Please copy and past the code under Built-in classes/structs exactly as it is. As I have already said before, `String` does not conform to `Identifiable`, so you will not be able to use `ForEach(asArray, id: \.self)` with it. The `id` parameter will only work if the class/struct conforms to identifiable. You will need to use `ForEach(0 ..< asArray.count)` instead.

Comment: Ok I dont really understand what you mean. The code wich you wrote under -Built-in classes/structs:- dont works for me... or I used i not correctly, if this is so, could you please explain it again?

Comment: I will repeat it again. If you are using an array of String, you will need to copy the code exactly as it is under Built-in classes/structs. String doesn't conform to Identifiable so your code will not work. The code that you have in your edited question is incorrect. If you are using a custom class, use the code under custom classes/structs.

Comment: It seems like all of this is a red herring since the OP said that their code *already* works with `ForEach`. However, I think the first line about `ScrollView` is likely the correct answer...

Comment: Oh bruh im a dumb idiot, i read over this line. Sorry for waisting your time

Comment: @jnpdx Yes, you are correct, but I wanted to point out the difference between using a type that conforms to Identifiable, and a type that doesn't conform to it just in case that could have been the issue. If you notice, the OP's question wasn't too clear about the problem, and the question was using `ForEach` incorrectly. Thank you for pointing it out though,

Comment: Actually, I don't think the OP had any issues with their original `ForEach` code -- using `\.self` is a perfectly valid solution for something like an `Array` of `String` (which they revealed in the comments).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I wasn't able to fully understand what the OP was saying which is why I added that.